# RxSwift - How to keep UICollectionView's contentOffSet and selection when data source changes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, rx-swift

Whenever there's an event on my items `Observable`, selection and contentOffset on `UICollectionView` is gone. Here's my binding code:

```
items.bind(to: collectionView.rx.items) { [weak self] collectionView, item, model in
            guard let `self` = self else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)) as! MyCollectionViewCell
            cell.configure(with: model)
            return cell
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I want items to be appended and keep the contentOffset and selection as is.

Answer (score 0):

If using RxDataSources, make sure to use `RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource`, which handles identifying which cells has been actually updated. `RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource` requires an item to be of `IdentifiableType` type, so please also make sure that every item's identity is actually unique.

Comment: I only have 0 section in my `collectionView`. Would RxDataSources work with single section?

Comment: I've implemented `RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource ` but still selection and contenOffSet is gone on next event.

Comment: Could you please share details of your `IdentifiableType` implementation?